# Duda con extracción de formulario

Tags: javascript, formularios

Lo que me gustaría hacer es que mientras el usuario va introduciendo los datos si el formato no es correcto las letras se vean rojas y si es correcto se vea verde.

Mi problema creo que es que a la hora de extraer los datos que introduce un usuario en un formulario el e-mail en este caso,al hacer en la comparación el x.value se extrae ningún dato de la x.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("mail");      
emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    
if (!emailRegex.test(x.value)) {
     x.style.color = "red";
    }else{
      x.style.color = "green";
    }
```

```html
<input type="email" id="mail" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinion es mejor que uses este CSS:

```css
input[type="email"]:invalid {
  color: red;
}

input[type="email"]:valid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
 <input type="email" id="mail" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail">
```

Sin embargo si quieres hacerlo por medio de js

```js
function validate(x){
emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

if (!emailRegex.test(x.value)) {
     x.style.color = "red";
    }else{
      x.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="mail" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" onkeyup="validate(this)">
```

Debes tener en cuenta usar eventos para este tipo de validaciones, en este caso usé onkeyup para que cada vez que el usuario escriba se realice la validación.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de implementar rápidamente lo que necesitas es utilizar **Bootstarp** con **jquery validator**.

Ademas puedes usar css de bootstarp en tu pagina ya que viene listo para utilizar.
Te paso una url donde esta implementado:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/bootstrap/index.html

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejare este sencillo ejemplo para que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades o requerimientos es con CSS3 pero te puede servir:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Title<abbr title="This field is mandatory">*</abbr></legend>
      <input type="radio" required name="title" id="r1" value="Sr" ><label 
      for="r1">Sr. </label>
      <input type="radio" required name="title" id="r2" value="Sra"><label 
      for="r2">Sra.</label>
    </fieldset>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="n1">¿Cuál es tu edad?</label>
    <!-- El atributo pattern puede actuar como fallback para navegadores que 
    no implementen el tipo number pero sí soporten el atributo pattern.
    Nótese que los navegadores que soportan el atributo pattern lo harán 
    fallar silenciosamente cuando se use con un campo numérico.
    Su uso aquí solo es como fallback -->
    <input type="number" min="12" max="120" step="1" id="n1" name="age"
     pattern="\d+">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t1">¿Cuál es tu fruta favorita?<abbr title="Este campo es 
obligatorio">*</abbr></label>
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="fruit" list="l1" required
       pattern="[Pp]l[áa]tano|[Cc]ereza|[Mm]anzana|[Ff]resa|[Ll]im[oó]n|
    [Nn]aranja">
    <datalist id="l1">
        <option>Plátano</option>
        <option>Cereza</option>
        <option>Manzana</option>
        <option>Fresa</option>
        <option>Limón</option>
        <option>Naranja</option>
    </datalist>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t2">¿Cuál es tu dirección de correo electrónico?</label>
    <input type="email" id="t2" name="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t3">Déjanos un mensaje corto</label>
    <textarea id="t3" name="msg" maxlength="140" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button>Enviar</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

**CSS3**

```
body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin : 0;
}

form {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

p > label {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=number],
textarea,
fieldset {
/* requerido para estilizar adecuadamente elementos
   de formulario en navegadores basados en WebKit */
   -webkit-appearance: none;

  width : 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;

  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:invalid {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
}
```

Pagina fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Validacion_formulario_datos